# How do I make Require.js fetch a script that does not end in `.js`?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm developing an app that uses a certain site to make payments easier, and the way it handles payments requires to import some javascript from this url `https://bridge.paymill.com/` that contains the script.

The fact is, I'm using require js to load all the scripts, in my main.js configuration, I'm trying to make it this way:

```
requirejs.config({
  ...
  'paymill': 'https://bridge.paymill.com/',
  ...
});
```

But this, of course, tries to fetch from `https://bridge.paymill.com/.js`, which is not the correct url (it's without the last .js)

How could I notify requirejs to load this without appending '.js' at the end?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put a question mark at the end of the URL

```
requirejs.config({
  ...
  'paymill': 'https://bridge.paymill.com/?',
  ...
});
```

#### How this works:

`https://bridge.paymill.com/?.js` is a valid URL with `.js` as a GET request.

Comment: This is a bit of a hack but still will work like a charm, so +1 :-)